# Question about PI-Algebras (algebras with a polynomial identity)

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, algebras

I have a little trouble with a proof involving PI algebras, as you can see [here](https://books.google.it/books?id=LlnzBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA343&dq=giambruno%20asymptotic&hl=it&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) at page 6 - Giambruno Zaicev - *Polynomial Identities and Asymptotic methods*.

First of all let me recall some facts.

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field and $X$ a set. The free associative algebra on X over $\mathbb{F}$ is the algebra $\mathbb{F}\langle{X}\rangle$ of polynomials in the non-commuting indeterminates $x \in X$.

If $f\in \mathbb{F}\langle{X}\rangle$, we write $f=f(x_1,...,x_n)$ to indicate that $x_1,...,x_n \in X$ are the only indeterminates occurring in $f$.

We define $\deg u$, the degree of a monomial $u$, as the length of the word $u$. Also $\deg_{x_i} u$, is the number of occurrences of $x_i$ in $u$.

Accordingly, the degree $\deg f$ of a generic polynomial $f=f(x_1,...,x_n)$ is the maximum degree of a monomial in $f$; instead $\deg_{x_i} f$, the degree of $f$ in $x_i$, is the maximum of $\deg_{x_i} u$, for $u$ monomial in $f$.

**DEFINITION** Let $A$ be an $\mathbb{F}$-algebra and $f=f(x_1,...,x_n) \in \mathbb{F}\langle{X}\rangle$. We say that $f$ is a **polynomial identity** of $A$ if $f(a_1,...,a_n)=0$ for all $a_1,...,a_n \in A$ (shortly we can say that $f$ is a PI for $A$).

**DEFINITION** Let $f=f(x_1,...,x_n) \in \mathbb{F}\langle{X}\rangle$. We say that $f$ is multihomogeneous of multidegree $(a_1,...,a_n)$ if $f$ is a sum of monomials of degree $a_1$ in $x_1$,..., $a_n$ in $x_n$. In other words, if $f=\sum_{j=1}^{m}u_j$ where $u_j$'s are monomials of $f$ then $deg_{x_i}u_j=a_i\, \forall i=1,...,n\,\,j=1,...,m$.

**Example** $f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=x_2x_4x_1x_2x_1x_2+x_4{x_2}^2x_1x_2x_1$ is multihomogeneous of multidegree $(2,3,0,1)$.

If $f=f(x_1,...,x_n) \in \mathbb{F}\langle{X}\rangle$, we can always write $$f=\sum_{a_1\geq 0,...,a_n\geq 0} f^{(a_1,...,a_n)}$$ where $f^{(a_1,...,a_n)}$ is the sum of multihomogeneous monomials of multidegree $(a_1,...,a_n)$ of $f$, ie the sum of monomials in $f$ where $x_1,...,x_n$ appear at degree $a_1,...,a_n$ respectively. The polynomials $f^{(a_1,...,a_n)}$ wich are nonzero ar called multihomogeneous components of $f$.
Now the proposition I'm trying to understand:

> **Proposition** Let $\mathbb{F}$ be an infinite field. If $f=f(x_1,...,x_n) \in \mathbb{F}\langle{X}\rangle$ is a PI for the algebra A, then every multihomogeneous component of $f$ is still a PI for the algebra A.

**proof**. For every variable $x_t$, $1\leq t\leq n$, we can decompose $f=\sum_{i=0}^{m}f_i$ where $f_i$ is the sum of all monomials of $f$ in which $x_t$ appears at degree $i$ and $m=\deg_{x_t} f$ is the degree of $f$ at $x_t$.

Let $\alpha_0,...,\alpha_m$ be distinct elements of $\mathbb{F}$. Clearly for every $j=o,...,m$ $$f(x_1,...,\alpha_j x_t,...,x_n)$$ is still a PI for A. Since each $f_i$ is homogeneous in $x_t$ of degree $i$, $$f_i(x_1,...,\alpha_j x_t,...,x_n)={\alpha_j}^i f_i(x_1,..., x_t,...,x_n).$$
Hence $$f(a_1,...,\alpha_j a_t,...,a_n)=\sum_{i=0}^{m}{\alpha_j}^i f_i(a_1,...,a_n)=0$$ for all $j=0,...,m$ and for all $a_1,...,a_n \in A$.

Write the Vandermonde matrix $$\Delta=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\\ \alpha_0 & \alpha_1 & \cdots & \alpha_m \\ \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\ {\alpha_0}^m & {\alpha_1}^m & \cdots & {\alpha_m}^m \end{bmatrix}$$ then the previous says that for every $a_1,...,a_n \in A$, if we write $f_i(a_1,...,a_n)=\overline{f_i}$ then $$(\overline{f_0},...,\overline{f_m})\Delta=0$$ is a square linear system of equations which has a unique solution $(\overline{f_0},...,\overline{f_m})=(0,...,0)$ because $\det \Delta=\prod_{0\leq i<j\leq m}(\alpha_i-\alpha_j)$ is non-zero.
Then for every  variable $x_t$, $1\leq t\leq n$, if $f=\sum_{i=0}^{m}f_i$ where $f_i$ is the sum of all monomials of $f$ in which $x_t$ appears at degree $i$, then $f_0,...,f_m$ are PI for A.

### The author concludes the proof saying that by an **obvious induction argument** one can show that the theorem holds.

It's everything clear to me, **but** this obvious induction argument that I have to apply to a generic multihomogeneous component of $f$. I don't really know where to apply the inductive step (maybe on the number of multihomogeneous components of $f$?).

Any suggestion would be really appreciated! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the next step, fix now two variables: $x_{t_1},\ x_{t_2}$, and loop over their common degrees occuring in $f$:
$$f=\sum_{i_1,i_2\ge 0}f_{i_1,i_2}$$
where $f_{i_1,i_2}$ is the sum of monomials $m$ of $f$ where $\deg_{x_{t_1}}m=i_1$ and $\deg_{x_{t_2}}m=i_2$.

Note that for a fixed $i_1$, we get $\sum_{i_2\ge 0}f_{i_1,i_2}=f_{i_1}=$ the sum of monomials of $f$ where $\deg_{x_{t_1}}=i_1$.

By the above, we already know that $f_{i_1}$ is a PI for $A$, so we can apply it once again with $x_{t_2}$ to arrive that each $f_{i_1,i_2}$ is again PI for $A$.

Comment: I should've thought of that!!!!! Thank you so much Berci, your answere was illuminating for me.:-)